# Python: HELP getting runtime error(NZEC)

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime-error

So I've decided to take up competitive programming on CodeChef. I saw a problem to attempt. But I keep getting runtime error(NZEC) and I don't know why as I thought that error only occurred when I call out of bound array items and endless loops which takes too much memory.

**Problem**
1.) Get 2 inputs A and B 
2.) The boundaries: 1 ≤ B < A ≤ 10000
3.) Then I do A-B and alter a single digit of the answer
4.) Then I return it

Note:
 Time Limit is 1 sec, max source code size 50,000bytes

e.g

```
input A >> 95
input B >> 50

output >> 35
```

The actual answer is 45 but we're meant to alter one digit of the answer

So this was my solution

```
from random import randint

test1 = True
test2 = True

while test1:
    A = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    if (A>=1) and (A<=10000):
        test1 = False
    else:
        print("Number must be greater or equal to 1 and less than or equalts to 10,000")


while test2:
    B = int(input("Enter a second number: "))
    if (B>=1) and (B<=10000) and (B<A):
        test2 = False
    else:
        print("Number must follow rules as above BUT must be less than your first")

solution = str(A-B)
range1 = randint(0, len(solution)-1)
range2 = randint(0,9)
replacement = list(range(0,10))

new_solution = solution.replace(solution[range1], str(replacement[range2]))
print(new_solution)
```

Answer (score 0):

"NZEC" is not a specific error we can easily pinpoint and tell its cause. It simply means "Non-Zero Exit Code". This can mean that an error occurred somewhere in your code or your code execution simply took too long (these online judges usually have strict runtime restriction).

One possible cause is that the online judge tried to execute your code with string inputs which caused your calls to `int(input(..))` to raise a `ValueError` which your code doesn't catch.

Comment: I looked at other answers. They didn't even include code for testing if the user followed the boundaries. So definitely, string inputs testing is not the problem probably runtime restriction but I'm not sure.